# Investigate the convergence or divergence properties of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

Investigate the convergence or divergence properties of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$, where $a_n = \sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n}$.

I multiplied by its complex conjugate and resulted in $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}}.$ Then I tried applying the ratio test but that was inconclusive. I don't know how to apply the root test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither the root nor the ratio test will work.  You do have this
$$ \sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n} = {1\over \sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}  } \sim {1\over 2\sqrt{n}}. $$
How does $\sum_n 1/\sqrt{n}$ behave?

Answer (score 3):

Use telescoping to get
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^N a_n & = \sum_{n=1}^N (\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n})\\
& = (\sqrt{N+1} - \sqrt{N}) + (\sqrt{N} - \sqrt{N-1}) + \cdots + (\sqrt{3} - \sqrt2) + (\sqrt2- \sqrt1)\\
& = \sqrt{N+1} - 1
\end{align}
Now conclude what you want.

Comment: Nice direct solution.  Mine was a little more of an arabesque but it works too.

Comment: I can't conclude from this, it just gives me a ratio test of $1$ again.

Comment: @DonLarynx What is the definition of convergence of a series? Here we are looking at the sum of the first $N$ terms.